# Произведение ряда рекурсивно

Tags: c++, рекурсия, ряды

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с рекурсией. Изучаю эту тему сейчас на парах, и никак не могу допереть, как с ней работать. Нужно произведение ряда без циклов.
Буду благодарен за объяснения.[image: Задание]

```
// Lab7.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

double factorial(double a)
{
    if (a < 0)
{
    return 0;
}
    if (a == 1)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return a*factorial(a - 1);
}
}


double power(double a, double b)
{
if (b == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
    else
{
    return a*power(a, b - 1);
}
}



double sum(int k, int x)
{
double a = 1;
if (k = 1)
{
    a = ((power((1 - x), (k + 1))+1) / power((factorial(k - 1)) + 1, 2));
}
else
{
    a *= ((power((1 - x), (k + 1))+1) / power((factorial(k - 1)) + 1, 2));
    k--;
    sum(k, x);
}
cout << "Произведение ряда  = " << a << endl;
}
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
int x, n;
cout << "Введите x:" << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "Введите положительный n:" << endl;
cin >> n;
sum(n, x);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну свой ряд сами попробуйте сами разобрать.

А вот рекурсию я вам попробую объяснить на примере произвидения Валлиса:

[image: Произведение Валлиса]

Ну что же мы тут имеем?! Для каждого `i` посчитать значение выражения, а потом умножить его на текущий ответ. Т.е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь на что обратим внимание, а на то, что элементы каждого выражения связаны с предыдущим. **Т.е. 8 больше 6 на 2, 6 больше 4 на 2, 4 больше 2 на 2, видна закономерность???** Собственно эти размышления нас и приводят к первой формуле.

Так вот, если формула одна и та же, т.е. набор инструкций, чтобы прийти к ответу один и тот же, так почему бы и не использовать функцию для этого.

```
double vallis(double ans, int i) {
    // давайте в этой переменной мы будем хранить числитель
    int numerator = (2*i) * (2*i);
    // а в этой знаменатель
    int denumerator = (2*i - 1)*(2*i + 1);
    ans *= (double)numerator/denumerator;
    // Итак в текущем моменте нам известно, новое значение ans, но вот, что если мы хотели получить более точное значение `pi`? То давайте повторим весь набор инструкций для нового ans, а так же для чуток большего i.
    // Тут и приходит к нам на помощи рекурсия
    return vallis(ans, i+1);
}
```

Только наша функция будет работать вечно, так давайте же остaновим её в определённый момент, т.е. поставим ограничитель по глубине входа в рекурсию : `if (i > 20) return ans;` :

```
double vallis(double ans, int i) {
    if (i > 20) 
        return ans;
    int numerator = (2*i) * (2*i);
    int denumerator = (2*i - 1)*(2*i + 1);
    ans *= (double)numerator/denumerator;
    return vallis(ans, i+1);
}
```

Работает это как-то так : [image: картинка]

Comment: Обязательно изучу ваш материал, пригодится на зачёте :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

double customPow(double value, double power)
{
    if (power == 0) return 1;
    return value*customPow(value, power - 1);
}

double factorial(double value)
{
    if (value == 0) return 1;
    return value * factorial(value - 1);
}

double rowSum(double n, double k, double x)
{
    if (k > n) return 0;
    return (customPow(1 - x, k + 1) + 1) / customPow(factorial(k - 1) + 1, 2) + rowSum(n,k+1,x);
}

double rowMult(double n, double k, double x)
{
    if (k > n) return 1;
    return (customPow(1 - x, k + 1) + 1) / customPow(factorial(k - 1) + 1, 2) * rowMult(n, k + 1, x);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    double x, n;
    std::cout << "Введите x:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Введите положительный n:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "Cумма ряда = " << rowSum(n, 1, x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Произведение ряда = " << rowMult(n, 1, x) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно именно произведение ряда. Т.е. после значение после первой итерации умножится на произведение второй и так до введенного n

Comment: @СтаниславСоседов, добавил функцию произведения в пример (по сути отличается только знаком)

Comment: наконец-то я разобрался с вашей помощью, но программа после ввода обоих значений x и n закрывается с ошибкой..

Comment: @СтаниславСоседов, немного подправил код в ответе (в функции произведения забыл сменить вызов rowSum на rowMult), сейчас вроде все правильно. Насчет ошибки - она возникает именно при закрытии? С кодом из ответа?

Comment: Она возникает непосредственно после того, как введен n. Так как функции факториала и степени у меня идентичны вашим, я лишь добавил произведение и его вывод

Comment: @СтаниславСоседов, хм, а какие значения водите? При любых значениях? Пока в голову не приходит из-за чего, у меня скомпилировалось и вроде без ошибок отработало (Viusal Studio 2015)..

Comment: Это была моя ошибка в среде, всё успешно разрешилось. Спасибо огромное за подсказки :)